# How can I erase the history of passcodes on the iPhone4?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone4 running version iOS 4.3.  It is not jailbroken.  I want to re-use a previous passcode (the 4 number code to unlock the screen).  How can I get the iPhone to forget all the passcodes I've used in the past?

Comment: wait, what? does it even record such history? I don't see that on my iphone.

Comment: It must.  Yesterday it told me I had to change my passcode, and it won't let me change back to an old one - it says "This passcode has been used too recently".  This may be enforced through some setting required by my company.  But I have a hard enough time remember my new computer password!  I'll go nuts if I have to deal with a new iPhone passcode every few months.

Comment: Do you have a (Mail) Account of "Microsoft Exchange" type?

Comment: @VxJasonxV - yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're willing to jailbreak your only option is talk to your company's administrator. That policy is indeed enforced by the company, but maybe you're lucky and the responsible did it without caring too much about it. Anyways...

For changing the policy, try starting [here](http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/pdf/iPad_Security_Overview.pdf).

For removing the policy with jailbreak, you'll have to [read a lot](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=515690).

If you your Hit Points are below zero, [go to page 39](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfPU6DZIQhw&feature=player_embedded#at=95). <sub>(joking)</sub>

Comment: I'm currently working with the IT department to see why the phone demanded a new passcode; they don't seem to think it's a policy yet...

Comment: @KatieK it's right on the first page of the link I've sent you, they can't deny it. Seems like it might be easier to go on the jailbreak way! :)

Answer (score 2):

Many times password policies like this are enforced by looking at the most recent N passwords. For example, if a company requires changing your password every month, they may look at the last 12 passwords. I can't say for sure how it is implemented with the iPhone.

A simple trick to get around this is to change your password N times so that the password you want gets knocked off the list and you can use it again. If you don't know what the rule is and how many recent passwords are stored, it may take some trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me.  I just change the password 5 times, then on the 6th it let me use my original again.

Answer (score 0):

i reset my passcode 6 times, then reverted back to original. That worked. Not sure if the code then gets stored by 3rd party (in this case a linked email address to a work account)

Answer (score 0):

I had to change 10 times before it let me use my original one.  But then, no problem.